# How do I solve this discrete probability problem?

Tags: probability

> An instructor gives her class a set of $10$ problems with the information that the final exam will consist of a random selection of $5$ of them. If a student has figured out how to do $7$ of the problems, what is the probability that he
>   or she will answer correctly
>   (a) All $5$ problems?
>   (b) At least $4$ of the problems?

How do I find this probability because the fact that she knows 7 of the qustions is what is throwing me off? I know you have to find $\frac{\#E}{\#S}$ and $\#S= \binom{10}5$, but I am confused with the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, specifying the problem would help.

So there are 10 questions in total.
Let's number them like this:
Questions a-1~ a~10.

Now, the student knows how to solve 7 of them.
Let those be a-1 ~ a-7.

It really doesn't matter which of these 10 specific questions the student knows, just the fact that she knows one specific set of 7 questions is important.
That being said, no need to use 10combination7.

Now, the first one asks for the probability of the random 5 questions the teacher chooses being included in the a-1~ a-7.

7C5/10C5.

The second question,

would be the probability of choosing 4 + choosing 5,
thereby being
(7C4 x 3C1 + 7C5)/10C5

Thank you ozipone for pointing out my mistake:)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You labeled questions with the letter $a$?

Comment: Mm.. if you mean whether I used elementary coding,, no, just typing each one from my phone.

Comment: thanks, i cant believe it was that simple, i should have realized it sooner.

Comment: No problem :) I'm sure you would've gotten it by yourself

Comment: I don't understand how it is $\binom {7} {5}$. My understanding is that 5 questions has to be there in 7, so remaining 2 questions can be selected from remaining 5 (which are not in the exam) in $\binom {5} {2}$ ways. So #E = $\binom {5} {2}$.